# How to show related email on popup composeMailData - Vtiger

Tags: sugarcrm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have a custom module, in this module there is a field related to the account, then I create an email send button on the detail page, how can when the compose mail popup is displayed, the email of this account is added automatically.

EditView
[image]

DetailView (compose mail popup)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put that logic in your view controller. Take `vtigercrm/modules/Vtiger/views/ComposeEmail.php` as an example and create `vtigercrm/modules/YourCustomModule/views/ComposeEmail.php`

You need to do something similar to this when processing the request:

```php
$accountId = $request->get('accountid');
$account = Vtiger_Record_Model::getInstanceById($accountId);
$viewer = $this->getViewer($request);
$viewer->assign('TO', $account->get('email'));
```

Comment: Thank you, it's really what i needed